# Ionic Serve: Displays code only for a split second

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

My code is only shown for a split second after returning ionic serve and goes blank. I've everything needed to run this like nodejs, cordova, ionic, jdk, etc.
I'm new to ionic and would appreciate if someone can help me solve this.
This was run on internet explorer.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <h1>asdf</h1>
 <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

really you are very lost.
if you try to show

```
<h1>asdf</h1>
```

well that disappear because is replaced by the angular app in your code

```
    <!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

you do write your in angularjs for that you can check the docs of [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) and [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/).

you can retire the class of body and write direct in index but that is the really bad way

Comment: you do learn angular. Ionic can show any html/js/css code you put inside www but with that you only show a website and will be more hard use hybrid functionalities.  the better option for you is learn angular / ionic / cordova together, for that read the docs the 3 have a lot information and they're easy to learn. this will be produce better results.